# Looking for Solutions to Samsung's crappy number keyboard

Tags: android, html

So on most versions of Android, using a Samsung device, the `<input type="number">` pulls up the number pad, but does not allow the entry of a decimal.  From searching on the web, this is a known bug, but I've found very little talk regarding solutions or response from Samsung.

Anyone have a good idea to solve the problem?  Best I can come up with is writing a script that replaces `<input type="number">` with `<input type="tel">`. This brings up a number pad at least, and you can get to the decimal by tapping on the symbol key.

NOTE: I get the same behavior with or without the `pattern="[0-9\.]*"` attribute and/or the `step="any"` attribute.  Also, I'm looking for a pure web-based solution, not a native app solution.

Comment: Please don't give a "Use Google's Keyboard!" type of answer. Novice phone users that need to pay a bill will not know how to do this.

Comment: well if its a bug then the only solution seems to be another keyboard, no?

Comment: @tyczj technically, yes, but it's not a solution for a customer that doesn't know how to do this.  It's not real business / effortless user experience solution.

Comment: If this is for a banking solution where you know there will be two decimal places, one option would be to just automatically add two decimal places so each digit they enter moves the number one place to the right.  To enter 5.56 you would enter "556".  I'm not sure if this is the right type of application though.

Comment: @Ben I understand but its a problem Samsung needs to address and nothing you can really do about it except inform the user somehow about the issue. There are plenty of things Samsung likes to mess up in their software and this unfortunately is just another one. the only other thing I can think of is use some other character to indicate a decimal or use 2 input fields

Comment: you can use 2 input fields, one for numbers, one for decimals. you can use a `text` keyboard with javascript validation and with javascript preventing input of anything not a number. You can use a javascript virtual keypad, such as http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom keyboard using IME. Here is a link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: That is an interesting idea, but it looks like this is for native applications.  What I'm looking for is web browser accessed HTML solutions. (I'll clarify in my original question.)